# In solving $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, for $e ^{2ki\pi}$ , $\;k = 0,\pm1, \pm2, \ldots$ , why must "k" must be an integer?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In solving $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, when using the expression $e ^{2ki\pi}$ , $\;k = 0,\pm1, \pm2, \ldots$ , why must "$k$" must be an integer?

I understand there's a substitution going on, but why must "$k$" be **an integer**? Wouldn't that limit the range of the angle? I suppose in the original expression $z = e ^ {in\theta}$ where $\theta$ is **an arbitrary angle**. Why would a substitution using $2k\pi$ where k is an integer be equivalent as $n\theta$? As $n$ is **also an integer**, wouldn't that suggest that the original $\theta$ must also be a multiple of $2\pi$?

If I just ignore the "why" and keep going on, I can very well understand the process of solving roots of unity, but I am just a bit curious about this "why". I've searched for Wikipedia and textbooks and stuff but they all seem to not have a explanation...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is $e^{2k \pi i/n}$.

Comment: "Finding $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity" means solving the equation $z^n = 1$.  It's clear from taking absolute values that that $|z| = 1$, so write $z = e^{i\theta}$.  Now we have $e^{in\theta} = 1$, so $n\theta$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you Rhys. Your words also help! @Rhys

Comment: The question as stated by the title makes little sense. For any integer k, all of the expressions exp(2kπi) are equal to 1.  It is also entirely unclear what the O.P. means by "solving nth roots of unity". One solves an *equation* for an *unknown*. The nth roots of unity are neither equations nor unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction: The $n^{\text{th}}\;$ complex root of unity is represented by $$\text{exp}\left(\frac{2k\pi i}{n}\right), \text{ where}\; n, k\in \mathbb{Z},\;k \geq 0 \text{ and}\; n\geq 1.$$

Recall that the roots of unity are positioned equidistantly along the unit circle. The key is the "$2\pi$" in $2k\pi = k(2\pi)$. It might help to think of the $n^{\text{th}}\;$ roots of unity as forming a regular $n$-gon inscribed in the unit circle (for illustration, see [**this page**](http://www.mathematics-online.org/kurse/kurs7/seite52.html)).

Typically one considers only the roots $z_i$ (each of which is a solution to $z^n = 1$) for which $$z_i = e^{i\theta}, 0 \leq \theta =\frac{2k\pi}{n} < 2\pi,\; 1\leq i < n;\;k=0, 1, 2, ..., n-1.$$ For our purposes, in terms of finding complex roots of unity, $\;\theta = \theta + 2\pi = \theta + 4 \pi = \cdots$.

For an intuitive overview of complex roots of unity, see [**YouTube's video.**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RU9qgvdBgG0)

Comment: k and n needn't be coprime. For instance 4th root of 1 is 1,-1,i,-i.

Comment: Thank you very much. My first journey at math.stackexchange is certainly heartwarming :)

Comment: Sure no problem.

Comment: Complex style answer, Amy +). I hope to be here as it has been. :-)

Comment: Can you explain why we choose $k = 0,1,\ldots, n-1$ and not some other range for the $n$ roots of a complex number?

Comment: Your YouTube video is unavailable